# map query string parameter occurrences

Tags: linux, bash, grep, uniq

I have a log file with many query strings, for example:

```
param1=val1&param2=asd&p3=fgh&p4=jkl&width=100
```

I want to count each parameter unique values

I've tried to replaced '&' with new line, sort & get distinct values with the following command

```
tr '&' '\n' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

but it counts all of the parameters and **I need them to be sorted by key**, for example, current output :

```
2 width=1440
13 width=480
3 width=540
9 param1=3
8 param2=4
7 param1=2
```

requested output :

```
13 width=480
3 width=540
2 width=1440
..
9 param1=3
7 param1=2
..
8 param2=4
```

---

Update, better example:

```
$ cat test1.txt 
param1=val1&param2=asd&p3=fgh&p4=jkl&width=100
param1=val1&param2=asd&p3=fgh&p4=jkl&width=100
param1=val1&param2=asd&p3=fgh&p4=jkl&width=300
param1=val2&param2=asdf&p3=fgh3&p4=j3kl&width=200

$ cat test1.txt | tr '&' '\n'
param1=val1
param2=asd
p3=fgh
p4=jkl
width=100
param1=val1
param2=asd
p3=fgh
p4=jkl
width=100
param1=val1
param2=asd
p3=fgh
p4=jkl
width=300
param1=val2
param2=asdf
p3=fgh3
p4=j3kl
width=200
$ cat test1.txt | tr '&' '\n' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
      3 param2=asd
      3 param1=val1
      3 p4=jkl
      3 p3=fgh
      2 width=100
      1 width=300
      1 width=200
      1 param2=asdf
      1 param1=val2
      1 p4=j3kl
      1 p3=fgh3
```

**expected output:** 
group by parameter key

```
      3 param1=val1
      1 param1=val2
..
      2 width=100
      1 width=300
      1 width=200
...
      3 param2=asd
      1 param2=asdf
...
      3 p4=jkl
      1 p4=j3kl
...
      3 p3=fgh
      1 p3=fgh3
```

---

Couldn't decide if unix forum is better for this question

Comment: How does this come under `python` tag?

Comment: What is expected output for the input data shown?

Comment: @SachinKukreja I can pipe to "python -c", if it cannot be done via shell commands, my server comes with python v2.6.6, removed the python tag, why the down vote if I may ask ?

Comment: @anubhava like the requested output block, group by each key

Comment: Problem is that expected output doesn't match with the sample input provided.

Comment: @anubhava I'm sorry, I thought it can be concluded from the description, please look at my last edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `awk + sort + sed` command for doing this:

```
awk -F '&' -v OFS='=' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) freq[$i]++}
    END{for (i in freq) print freq[i], i}' file |
sort -t= -k2,2r -k1,1nr |
sed 's/=/ /'

2 width=100
1 width=200
1 width=300
3 param2=asd
1 param2=asdf
3 param1=val1
1 param1=val2
3 p4=jkl
1 p4=j3kl
3 p3=fgh
1 p3=fgh3
```

- `awk` command sets field separator as `&` and output field separator as `=` and counts frequency of each `name=value` parameter and prints `=` delimited output.
- `sort` command uses `=` as delimiter to reverse sort on field2 and field1 (numeric)
- `sed` command replaces first `=` by space to get your formatted output.

Comment: first of all thanks, useful +1, before I mark as answer can you please give a little explanation ? so I will understand where how to add delimiter between the keys